# Rapid HTML site creation

Tags: html-editor

I'm looking for a GUI based software that allows the rapid development of HTML website, preferably using bootstrap or other grid system. It must be minimalistic, so not DreamWeaver, and the output should be standards based. It must have a set of pre-defined elements that can be used and edited. Ideally it should be free or buy-to-own not subscription based.

The core aim is an app that allows rapid development pretty much as the expense of everything else.

Comment: Should it be WYSIWYG, or are you OK with coding too?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes coding is fine.